# How come the current owners don't know what's going on in hotel Cortez in Season 5?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-horror-story

In the hotel Cortez in American Horror Story 5, there seem to be murders and strange events occurring almost on a daily basis. But somehow the owners (or anyone else) don't seem to know or react to any of it. The hotel seems to be open for new guests because we do see new people coming in and at least some staff working. How come missing guests are never reported or dead bodies never found?

For example, in one episode, some workers restructuring a wall enter a hallway and are murdered and then at least 3 guests are murdered. The coworkers of the murdered workers are standing right there at the other end of the hallway, yet they don't care that two of their guys never came back! They should either find the dead bodies or report some team members missing. The murdered guests' families should come looking. Teams of cops should be all over the hotel looking for missing people. But none of it is ever seen, no disappearances are ever traced to the hotel, workers/staff never question anything and everything appears as usual. Further, the barman is apparently appointed by the countess but do the real owners know who he is? How does he get paid and stuff?

How come the current management and the rest of the world are so clueless?